# Can i show an outputfield or inputfield based on a boolean variable in VF page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a boolean variable and based on whether this is true or false i want to show a field as inputfield or outputfield.

```
   {!IF(!Showinput), <apex:outputField value="{!a.field1__c}"/>, apex:inputField value="{!a.field1__c}"/>)}
   <apex:inputField value="{!a.field2__c}"/>
```

When i try to save i get a error

```
  Error: Attribute value in <apex:inputField> must contain only a formula expression that resolves to a single controller variable or method
```

Is there any other way of achieving this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify both but use `rendered` attribute to control which one gets rendered

```
<apex:outputField value="{!a.field1__c}" rendered="{!NOT(Showinput)}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!a.field1__c}" rendered="{!Showinput}"/>
```